# Alter table enable keys and myisamchk

Tags: mysql, myisam, alter-table

I am doing import of large data into MYSQL myisam table. Is there any difference if I use ALTER TABLE for disable/enable keys or myisamchk tool?

```
ALTER TABLE DISABLE KEYS; 
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file' INTO TABLE table;
ALTER TABLE ENABLE KEYS;
```

VS

```
myisamchk --keys-used=0 -rq path\templatelinks
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file' INTO TABLE table;
myisamchk -rq path\table
```

I have checked both and found that ALTER TABLE is about 30% faster. Are there any other differences or both just do the same?

Comment: ALTER TABLE might have been faster because myisamchk doesn't use mysqld configuration (myisam_sort_buffer_size). So if you changed your default mysql configuration then that is probably why.

Answer (score 2):

No, both don't do the same functionality. If you want load data more quickly, you can disable/enable keys accordingly what you did already. I believe you'll get faster performance using myisamchk utility if you use  --keys-used=0 as follows:

```
myisamchk --keys-used=0 -rq path\table
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to import enwiki's page.sql.gz from https://dumps.wikimedia.org/backup-index-bydb.html. It has 35M records, the .gz size is around 1.2GB.

A) use the default "alter table page disable keys" in sql script

This could be fast in the begining(1MB/s), and then slower and slower(down to 100KB/s after 30minutes), then even worse.

```
pv enwiki-20150205-page.sql.gz | gzip -cd | sed 's/ENGINE=InnoDB/ENGINE=MyISAM/ | mysql enwiki
```

When importing data, mysql loaded data into page.MYD, and updated page.MYI simultaneously.

B) use myisamchk, done in around 20 minutes

```
# create empty table
zcat enwiki-20150205-page.sql.gz | sed '/^)/q' | sed 's/ENGINE=InnoDB/ENGINE=MyISAM/' | mysql enwiki
# use myisamchk
myisamchk --keys-used=0 -rq /var/lib/mysql/enwiki/page
# 9min to load data, 12min to re-index (triggered by "enable keys" in script)
pv enwiki-20150205-page.sql.gz | gzip -cd | sed '/^DROP TABLE.*;$/d' | sed '/^CREATE TABLE/,/^).*;$/d' | mysql enwiki
```

When importing data, mysql loaded data into page.MYD first, after that, page.MYI was updated separately.

C) I perfer `myisamchk --keys-used=0 -rq /var/lib/mysql/enwiki/page`. Much more efficient.

According to p.1425 on `mysql-refman-5.7-en.pdf`:
        Use ALTER TABLE ... DISABLE KEYS to tell MySQL to stop updating **nonunique** indexes

So if there are any **nonunique** indexes, use myisamchk to disable keys.

On the other hand, I compared `myisamchk -rq /var/lib/mysql/enwiki/page` and `alter table page disable keys`, they seems equivalent.